# Usage of SSL in Node.js app proxied trough Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl, https

I have this structure: `Client -> Cloudflare -> Apache Server -> Node.js Express`

Am I supposted to use HTTPS protocol on Node.js Express app? Or its completely pointless because I already have SSL enabled on `Client -> Cloudflare -> Apache Server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer without more details on your application, but I will say that it's very common to terminate SSL at the load balancer or web server, and then have the web server or load balancer reverse proxy to the node app over HTTP or a unix socket or similar.  I wouldn't say it's completely "pointless", but it is more overhead that will depend on the level of security you require.

In most cases, if the Apache web server is on the same machine as the node application, or if there's some other protection between the two machines, then there's little or no value to be gained by also encrypting that traffic.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have Node.js server and Apache on same machine so it seems overhead to have it. I have now bigger problem and its related to direct access to nodejs server port. How can I deny direct access?

Comment: Use your firewall, whether that's on the machine or on the network. That's what it's there for.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see you can restrict acces inside nodejs app too by checking origin Ip, but firewall seems better option :)